# Spring @Before changing every user login

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a @Aspect class, that execute a @Before method and intercept all queries with some Id from the login of user. But the problem is: every time a user make login, the Id from @Before method change for all logged users, it just must to change the current user.

**The simple process:** when a user make login, the @Aspect class gets his id to intercept all queries. But this id is changing for every logged user. Maybe should be a problem with session, I really do not know.

The aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class TenancyAspect {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Autowired
    private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

    @Before("execution(* com.tc.tcqualidade.repository.*.*(..)) "
            +"&& !execution(* com.tc.tcqualidade.repository.UsuarioRepository.porEmailEStatus(..))"
            +"&& !execution(* com.tc.tcqualidade.repository.UsuarioRepository.permissoes(..))")
    public void definirTenant() {
        String tenantid = appUserDetailsService.getTenantId();

        if (tenantid != null) {
            manager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("tenant").setParameter("id", tenantid);
        }

    }

}
```

The login class:

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private String tenantId = null;

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Usuario> usuarioOptional = usuarioRepository.porEmailEStatus(email);
        Usuario usuario = usuarioOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuário e/ou senha incorretos"));

        tenantId = usuario.getEmpresa().getId().toString();

        return new UsuarioSistema(usuario, getPermissoes(usuario));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getPermissoes(Usuario usuario) {
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

        List<String> permissoes = usuarioRepository.permissoes(usuario);
        permissoes.forEach(p -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p.toUpperCase())));

        return authorities;
    }

    public String getTenantId(){
        return tenantId;
    }

}
```

Comment: "every time a user signs in" how? I mean you probably should add to your question some details about your whole process

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question, have a look, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this same behaviour when using @Autowired. Spring will not create a new instance on each access unless you tell it do so, so the object is shared across all accesses. A user logging in, caused all logged in users to change to that user's id. You might need to make one of your services session scoped:

```
@Service
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

Comment: Hey! I have tried this in my Aspect class, but didn't work, now in my Service class works! thank you so much, man!