# rest api data mismatch in concurrent request

Tags: java, spring, rest, concurrency

In my project we are using restful webservices with spring framework, when I call the same request concurrently the property of the 
object is overriden by one another.

Below is my code.

```
@Service("testService")
@Scope(value ="prototype")
public class TestServiceImpl extends DefaultServiceBuilder {

        public void test() {
                 process();
                 System.err.println(tranLog.getTxnId());

        }
}


  public class DefaultServiceBuilder {

protected TransactionLog tranLog;

public void process() {
    tranLog = new TransactionLog();
    Random r = new Random();
    String rid = r.nextInt(40000)+"";
    tranLog.setTxnid(rid);
    setTranLog(tranLog);
}


    public TransactionLog getTranLog() {
        return tranLog;
    }

    public void setTranLog(TransactionLog tranLog) {
        this.tranLog = tranLog;
    }
}

public class TransactionLog {
   private String txnId;

   public void setTxnId(String txnId) {
        this.txnId = txnId;
   }

   public String getTxnId() {
        return txnId;
   }
}
```

I am calling the below request with 2 thread parallel.

```
My expected input is 
123456
242422

But the output is 
242422
242422
```

Why the TransactionLog object value is overriding eventhough i gave scope prototype.
How to access the Transalog object safely?

Any help will be greatly Appreciated!!!!

Comment: What is reat API?

Comment: @Hellzonse sorry typo mistake its rest

Comment: if it is two different request altogether, then it shouldn't affected. Can you post your thread code ?\

Comment: @Ravi, we faced this issue in production.I simulated the same thing using @RunWith(ConcurrentTestRunner.class) with junit

Comment: @Ravi the issue occurs if either the same class or different methods of the class called at same time or the request processing time.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, even it is happening for some reason. then you could probably synchronize it.

Comment: is it related to the scope? I had this type of issue and changing the scope also solved a similar issue for someone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201738/spring-before-changing-every-user-login/47202370#47202370

Comment: @Codebrane, Thanks, after adding proxy attribute issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could synchronize your code, by synchronizing below line of code

```
protected static TransactionLog tranLog;

public static synchronized void process() {
    Random r = new Random();
    tranLog = new TransactionLog();
    String rid = r.nextInt(40000)+"";
    tranLog.setTxnid(rid);
}
```

Making `static synchronized` will allow only one thread at any given time.

Comment: thanks for the solution but it does not prevent the value overriden.still the last value only coming in response

Comment: @Madhesh You mean, you are still getting same issue ?

Comment: yes @Ravi, still i am getting last value only.Object creation is not an issue. I have to synchronize the protected TransactionLog transactionLog variable.

Comment: @Madhesh any specific reason for declaring `protected TransactionLog tranLog;` as `protected` ?

Comment: yes, In my project every class transactionId we created from defaultservice class. so  every service class we are extending that.As of now  6600 request has this issue in 60 billion request

Comment: @Madhesh I'm sure, how that help. But, I have made few correction. and It should give you expected output

Comment: thanks @Ravi, now the issue fixed partially. now i can able to generate different ids but the next thread execution completes value again changing.Is it any other way to make that particular object alone synchronized?

Comment: @Madhesh No, it seems like there are multiple thread and using same object and that's the reason I made synchronization on object first. But, you mentioned it wasn't working. So, I proposed this solution. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it was helful :-)

Comment: thanks for the help after adding proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS issue is resolved

Comment: @Madhesh As I said earlier, there was something specific to your application otherwise it isn't expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Class name *TransactionLog* implies that evety instance of *TransactionLog*, writed to variable *tranLog* will be used only in one thread.

If it right, then read further:

In very good book "Java Concurrency in Practice" described one good pattern of thread synchronization:

> **Thread Confinement**
>
> Accessing shared, mutable data requires using synchronization; one way to avoid this requirement is to not share. If data is only accessed from a single thread, no synchronization is needed. This technique, thread confinement, is one of the simplest ways to achieve thread safety. When an object is confined to a thread, such usage is automatically thread-safe even if the confined object itself is not [CPJ 2.3.2].

Make field *tranLog* just local variable

```
final TransactionLog tranLog = new TransactionLog();
```

If you use it in other function, for instance *subProcess2*:

```
private void subProcess2() {
    tranLog.doSometthing();
}
```

Add *tranLog* to function parameters:

```
private void subProcess2(TransactionLog tranLog) {
    tranLog.doSometthing();
}
```

And pass *tranLog* when calling *subProcess2*.

Comment: thanks it really helpful.but to implement this solution we have to change every request.Is it possible to synchronize that TransactionLog object alone in any other way?